# Dynamic Tabs by selecting the option on Menu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm kinda new to the JSF and Web Programming, i'm using primefaces 6.0 and trying to have a TOP MENU, that opens TabView. Everytime that you select an option on the TOP MENU, opens a new Tab on the TabView with the content of that selected option.

[image: 1. Click on the menu button || 2. the selected tab opens || 3. The content is shown.]

I was searching but didn't found how to do it.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters I suggest you use the `<p:layout>`component to divide your page, and for displaying the content in tabs I suggest you use `<ui:include>`you can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets).
So your main page should look something like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>

<body>
    <p:layout>
        <p:layoutUnit position="north">
            <!-- !!!!!!!!!! Menu goes here !!!!!!!!!!! -->
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="center" resizable="false">
            <p:tabView>
                <p:tab title="Title goes here">
                    <ui:include src="content" />
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</body>

</html>
```

Note : In case you want to generate your tabs dynamically you'd want to create a custom Tab class and use JSTL's `<c:forEach>` to loop over the tabs to populate the tabView.

**xhtml :**

```
<p:tabView>
    <c:forEach items="#{homeView.openTabs}" var="tab">
        <p:tab title="#{tab.title}" closable="true" rendered="#{tab.open}">
            <ui:include src="#{tab.content}"/>
        </p:tab>
    </c:forEach>
</p:tabView>
```

Note that `openTabs` is an ArrayList of Tabs.

**Custom tab class :**

```
public class Tab {

    private String title;
    private String content;
    private boolean open;

//Custom constructor, getters and setters...
```

**Tips :**
Use the `<p:tab>` rendered attribute to handle closing and reopening tabs. Be sure to use tabView's custom event `<p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{homeView.onTabClose}"/>` for advanced event handling.